# Automate marking new Leads as read

Tags: sales-cloud, automation

Is it possible to have other activities mark a Lead as read? We have a use case where some of our users would like to mark Leads as read when they have been included in an Extended Mail Merge.

Example: Twenty new Leads come in and are responded to via Extended Mail Merge. Instead of having to click-through to each Lead they should now be marked as read.

I know that we can do this via the Data Loader so I'm hoping there might be a way to do this with triggers or in mass on a Visualforce page.

Comment: Is mass editing using enhanced lists  with standard list views an option ? You could also do a mass effect JavaScript button using the Ajax toolkit to action items selected in a list view.

Comment: This is not editable via enhanced lists.

Comment: If the email is logged against each as a Task, then perhaps a TaskAfter trigger?

Comment: It shows up in the Activity History with Task checked, so I guess that's possible?

Comment: Might be worth investigating. Although if SteveMo reckons it ain't possible it prolly ain't :) http://success.salesforce.com/questionDetail?qId=a1X30000000drAWEAY

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just tried a Mass effect button added to the List view, and it seems to be able to update the field on the lead, returns a successful result. Create a List Button, with on click JS behaviour, paste in the JS below and add it to the Lead List View Search Layout. (You can also set IsUnreadByOwner to true, to mark them unread, seemingly. Managed to query via Workbench to verify.)

```
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/26.0/connection.js")}
var records = {!GETRECORDIDS($ObjectType.Lead)}; 
var updateRecords = []; 

if (records[0] == null) { 
    alert("Please select at least one record to update."); 
} else { //otherwise, there was a record selection
    for (var a=0; a<records.length; a++) { //for all records
        var update_Lead = new sforce.SObject("Lead");
        update_Lead.Id = records[a];
        update_Lead.IsUnreadByOwner = "false"; 
        updateRecords.push(update_Lead); 
    }
    result = sforce.connection.update(updateRecords); 
       alert('Result is ' + result);

}
```

Comment: Thanks! I like the simplicity that having a dedicated button for this could bring. One question: do the updates have to happen individually or can they be done in bulk?

Comment: Thanks. The updates are happening in bulk when a list of leads is passed through via the update Api call on the last line.

Comment: I'll have to try this out this week.

Answer (score 3):

It turns out that a free 3rd party app from the App Exchange for handling mass edits and updates provides this functionality.

**Edit**

As requested, the app is [Mass Update and Mass Edit](http://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N300000018mbBEAQ) by Salesforce Labs.

Comment: Interesting. Could you provide a link or the name of the app?

Comment: Answer updated to provide name and link of the app.