# Update a checkbox on all records in a related list from a related list button with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, custom-button

I need to allow a user to select one or more records from a related list and click a button on that related list that sets a checkbox to true on each selected record.

I have prepared the following javascript in a custom button and displayed checkboxes in the related list.

Currently, when the button is clicked, the records are not updating and the checkboxes are not getting set.

Custom object: FF__Team_Member_*c
Custom field: Checkbox on FF*_Team_Member__c : Send_Email_to_Team_Member__c

Any thoughts?

```
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/20.0/connection.js")} 

var records = {!GETRECORDIDS($ObjectType.FF__Team_Member__c)}; 
var updateRecords = []; 

if (records[0] == null) { 
    alert("Please select at least one record to update.");  
} else { 
    for (var a=0; a<records.length; a++) { 
        var update_TeamMember = new sforce.SObject("FF__Team_Member__c");
        update_TeamMember.Id = records[a];
        update_TeamMember.Send_Email_to_Team_Member__c = true;
        updateRecords.push(update_TeamMember);
    }
    result = sforce.connection.update(updateRecords); 
location.reload(true);
}
```

Comment: You may want to look at a similar question I asked - http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/3581/automate-marking-new-leads-as-read

Answer (score 4):

This should work, I can think only of couple problems here:

1. Are you on iPhone/iPad? There were some known bugs with GETRECORDIDS not working properly on iSafari (regular Safari seems to be fine).
2. Are you sure the object name is typed correctly? It has 2 underscores = `FF` must be a managed package? Is current user allowed to edit them etc etc? (even if you're sysadmin objects might appear invisible - not returned in describe results if Profile permissions aren't set)
3. Any validation rules /trigger-based checks you might be hitting over there? You're swallowing all results which might contain errors. Perform simple `alert(results);` or maybe sth like this:

---

```
for(var i = 0; i < results.length; ++i){
    if (result[i].getBoolean("success")) {
        log("record with id " + result[i].id + " updated");
    } else {
        log("failed to update record " + result[i]);
    }
}
```

(inspect the browsers JS console afterwards or replace log with alert but then make sure to not tick too many checkboxes ;))

Comment: Thanks! there is an active trigger on the custom object. Let me take another look and even try my code (with your log addition) on another object I know has no triggers.

Comment: The JS console in Chrome revealed this error message: `failed to update record {errors:{fields:null, message:'sObject type 'FF__Team_Member__c' is not supported. If you are attempting to use a custom object, be sure to append the '__c' after the entity name. Please reference your WSDL or the describe call for the appropriate names.', statusCode:'INVALID_TYPE', }, id:null, success:'false', }`

Comment: @SteveRichardson Are you really really sure you haven't mistyped the object's name? It will have only 1 underscore after "FF' if it's your own custom object and not coming from an installed package. What's the "API" name if you view it in Setup (upper right corner) -> Create -> Objects. Are you sure you have "Read" and "Update" permissions to it (even if you're sysadmin - check your Profile)...

Comment: I'm the package developer. This managed pkg is installed into a subscriber org. I'm working as a System Admin in the subscriber org. The API name from Setup is: FF__Team_Member__c

Comment: I've probably screwed it up but hopefully you got some notification about the chat room I tried to set up... http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/6573/discussion-between-steve-richardson-eyescream

Comment: This question is still unanswered. SFDC partner support will not support Javascript. It seems the JS is sound based on others' reviews yet the statement `new sforce.SObject("FF__Team_Member__c");` referencing the custom object is considered invalid. Any additional help is appreciated. @eyescream thanks for your help to date!

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the similar problem of 'INVALID_TYPE' when trying to update an array of Cases. After a long time I found out that the sforce.connection.update method only takes a SINGLE object at a time for updation. Since we were both passing an ARRAY, the call failed. Try passing only a single record and it should work fine.

There has to be something though to work with a collection.

Answer (score 0):

Please update this line, you forget to add the id.
**update_TeamMember.Id = records[a].id;**